# Confused about 'and' keyword

Tags: perl

Why do these 2 pieces of code yield different outputs?

```
    $a = 3;
    ($a == 4) and print "But I wanted apple, cherry, or blueberry!\n" ;
```

gives No program output but

```
    $a = 3;
    print "But I wanted apple, cherry, or blueberry!\n" and ($a == 4);
```

gives: But I wanted apple, cherry, or blueberry!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `and` is a so-called ["short circuit" operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). Meaning that if you have `condition1 and condition2`, then the first condition is evaluated, and only if the first condition returns true is the second condition evaluated.

So, in

```
$a = 3;
($a == 4) and print "But I wanted apple, cherry, or blueberry!\n" ;
```

the condition `$a==4` is false and so the `print` statement isn't evaluated.

However, in

```
$a = 3;
print "But I wanted apple, cherry, or blueberry!\n" and ($a == 4);
```

The `print` statement does its thing and [returns `true`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html). The second condition is evaluated (which is obviously `false`), but the printing is already done.

Answer (score 6):

The truth table for AND and OR is

```
p  q  p AND q  p OR q
-  -  -------  ------
F  F     F       F
F  T     F       T
T  F     F       T
T  T     T       T
```

Or if we group,

```
p  q  p AND q         p  q  p OR q
-  -  -------         -  -  ------
F  *     F            F  F    F
T  F     F            F  T    T
T  T     T            T  *    T
```

In other words, it's not always necessary to evaluate both operands to know the final result.

Perl (among other languages) incorporates that as a feature: It will "short-circuit" the evaluation of boolean operators by returning as soon as possible. Not only is it a good optimisation, it's very useful. It allows these constructs to be meaningful:

```
 func(...)
    or die;

 condition(...)
    and next;
```

Without the short-circuiting, `die` and `next` would be evaluated unconditionally.

If you want to evaluate both operands, you'll need temporary variables

```
 my $f = f();  # f() has side-effects!
 my $g = g();  # g() has side-effects!
 if ($f && $g) {
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

In Perl, `and` is a short circuit operator.

[PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=301355) explains short circuit operators nicely:

> **Why "Short Circuit?"**
>
> Camel II tells us that the term "Short-Circuit" refers to the fact that they "determine the truth of the statement by evaluating the fewest number of operands possible." So essentially these operators stop the chain of evaluation of an expression as early as possible. That is another key to their value.

Basically, if the left side of the `and` statement is false, the right side isn't evaluated at all.

Comment: I thought 'and' was an 'all or nothing' operator, so it would print only if all other conditions were true as well.

Comment: Your `print` statement is a part of the condition. If you had something like `if (condition) { print "..."; }`, the `print` statement would only execute if `condition == true`, but this isn't the case.

Answer (score -1):

If you're ever uncertain about precedence (which operators run first, and which run last), you can always have Perl parse your code and then de-parse it again with maximal usage of parentheses turned on:

```
perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e '($a == 4) and print "But I wanted apple, cherry, or blueberry!\n" ;'
```

Which outputs:

```
(($a == 4) and print("But I wanted apple, cherry, or blueberry!\n"));
```

Comment: This is irrelevant. The question is about which of the operands are evaluated at all.